# Fetch XML without getting blocked (CORB)

Tags: javascript, xml, cross-origin-read-blocking

For example I want to fetch https://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml 
to my website http://example.com.

This is the code

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", 'https://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml', true);
xhr.onload = function () {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
    console.log(this);
 }
}

xhr.send();
```

I'm getting an empty response and a warning saying

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml with MIME type text/xml. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

Then I had been studying these CORB rules. Some developers are saying that it is not possible to get data from another origin. 
But is it really the case?

In the project I'm working on, it is a public xml feed, and since the owner are updating the feed quite often - and I would like to have my website in sync with the feed - I assume it is not possible? Do I really have to create a xml file, and copy-paste the xml data and upload it to my server each time?

Or is there a way to fetch this data directly from the url somehow?

Comment: Maybe it helps if you set a user-agent header. This helped me to bypass the reddit api block

Comment: Can you make an example? Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend using a proxy. With any backend of your choosing, make the `GET` call to w3schools, then with JavaScript do a `GET` call to your proxy, that should entirely avoid all `CORS` issues.

Comment: `xhr.setRequestHeader('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36');` This will let the server think you are opening the page from Google Chome

Answer (score 0):

You could create a PHP script like this:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/xml");
    echo file_get_contents('https://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml');
?>
```

Call this `simple.php` and then amend your Javascript to call `simple.php` instead:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", 'simple.php', true);
xhr.onload = function () {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
    console.log(this);
 }
}

xhr.send();
```